# forming a list of tuples by iterating over lines in document

Tags: python

I'm writing a function to read in a document.  This is the Penn Treebank corpus where each word has a corresponding part of speech tag, separated by tab space ('\t').  Each sentence is separated by a blank line ('\n') where I need to strip out tabs and empty(blank) lines.  The word and it's corresponding tag should be inserted into a tuple, and the entire corpus would be then a list of tuples.  An example sentence looks like this:

```
Pierre  NNP
Vinken  NNP
,   ,
61  CD
years   NNS
old JJ
,   ,
will    MD
join    VB
the DT
board   NN
as  IN
a   DT
nonexecutive    JJ
director    NN
Nov.    NNP
29  CD
.   .
```

Each tuple should look like this (this is one of many):

```
[('Pierre', 'NNP'), ....]
```

I am reading the file correctly, and parsing the lines into pairs; however, I get an indexing error:

```
ptbtagged_path = 'data/PTBSmall/train.tagged'
list_of_tups=[]
with open(ptbtagged_path, "r") as fp:
    for line in fp:
        parts=line.split('\t')
        list_of_tups.append((parts[0],parts[1][:-1]))
```

=================

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_14/344846302.py in <cell line: 10>()
     11     for line in fp:
     12         parts=line.split('\t')
---> 13         list_of_tups.append((parts[0],parts[1][:-1]))

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Also, I am not successful in removing the whitespace, as my "parts" variable when printed looks like this:

```
['Pierre', 'NNP\n']
```

I am thinking i need to iterate over the second element in the list to remove the '\n', but I was also thinking there might be a more pythonic, clean way to do this.  Thoughts?

Comment: Why do you put a list inside the tuple? Shouldn't it be `('Pierre', 'NNP')`?

Comment: OP you say you should have a list of tuples at the end, but your example shows a tuple of lists. Can you please clarify?

Comment: When the error occurs, the line being split must not be what you expect - [Catch the error](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) and inspect/print relevant data in the except suite. You might want to use enumerate in the for loop so you can quickly find the line in the text file.

Comment: It seems like you just need to skip blank lines that are between sentences, since `split()` won't return 2 elements.

Comment: Regarding @Barmar's comment and the questions surrounding that, I updated the output (it was residual from a permutation I had been trying), so it truly is a "list of tuples" that I am looking for.  I  will try the answers below.  Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Use

- `.rstrip()` to remove the newline from each line
- the limit parameter to `.split()` to get up to 2 items
- a list comprehension to iterate over the lines in the file

like so:

```
with open(ptbtagged_path, "r") as fp:
    list_of_tups = [line.rstrip("\n").split("\t", 1) for line in fp]
```

- If there are empty lines to filter out, you could add `if line.strip()` after `in fp`.
- If you especially need a tuple, wrap the `line.rstrip...` bit in `tuple()`.

Comment: `split()` returns a list, not a tuple.

Comment: @Barmar Sure. Added a note about that.

Comment: His example has a list inside a tuple. I'm not sure why, though. So it should be `(line.rstrip("\n").split("\t", 1),)`

Comment: If that's really what they want, sure. I'm not sure that it really is, though.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, i would do:

```py
ptbtagged_path = 'data/PTBSmall/train.tagged'
list_of_tups=[]
with open(ptbtagged_path, "r") as fp:
    for line in fp.read().split("\n"):
        parts=line.split('\t') 
        list_of_tups.append(parts)
```

Comment: This solution definitely removed the whitespace represented by "\n", but it created a list of lists (which look like tuples but actually are lists.  See the result below:  

`[['Pierre', 'NNP'], ['Vinken', 'NNP'], [',', ','],....]`

Thank you though!

Comment: Im sorry i forgot, you need to do list_of_tups.append(tuple(parts))